# LXC on raspberrypi using raspbian OS

Tags: lxc

Mount a cgroup

## pico /etc/fstab

## add the line “lxc /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup defaults 0 0”

## mount -a

Create a Directory to Store Hosts

## mkdir -p /var/lxc/guests

Create a File System for the Container

Let’s create a container called “test”.

First, create a filesystem for the container. This may take some time

## apt-get install debootstrap

## mkdir -p /var/lxc/guests/test

## debootstrap wheezy /var/lxc/guests/test/fs/ http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian

Modify the Container’s File System

## chroot /var/lxc/guests/test/fs/

Change the root password.

## passwd

Change the hostname as you wish.

## pico /etc/hostname

undo chroot

## exit

Create a Minimal Configuration File

## pico /var/lxc/guests/test/config

Enter the following:

lxc.utsname = test

lxc.tty = 2

lxc.rootfs = /var/lxc/guests/test/fs

Create the Container

lxc-create -f /var/lxc/guests/test/config -n test

Test the Container

## lxc-start -n test -d

And this error came up

lxc-start: symbol lookup error: lxc-start: undefined symbol: current_config